# Cannot repair file in Windows 8.1

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 64 bit running Windows Update continuously.

Suddenly I had significant problem getting the laptop started. Refresh, recovery, reset, restore did not work. Recovery would not recognize the recovery disk. After trying boot options 1, 4 and 5, option 7 finally got it back alive.

Afterwards I have been trying to see if the OS is corrupted. And is of course hesitant to turn off the laptop for example to check the harddisk with chkdsk.

DISM even when pointing to the windows iso DVD still returns with the message that "The source files could not be found". And sfc /scannow "found corrupt files". I tried to run this a couple of times.

Looked in the CBS file and searched for the text "cannot repair member file", there only seem to be one file. Here is the first entry with the error message:
2014-07-05 13:05:37, Info CSI 000005c6 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:36{18}]"Amd64\CNBJ2530.DPB" of prncacla.inf, Version = 6.3.9600.16384, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type = [l:24{12}]"driverUpdate", TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch

Comment: before trying to fix this, please copy the file CNBJ2530.DPB from **Windows\WinSxS\amd64_prncacla.inf_31bf3856ad364e35_6.3.9600.16384_none_9590ba64d5b91f79\Amd64** to your desktop and upload it (OneDrive, other clod service). Microsoft is currently trying to find the causes of the corruption of this file. After you copied the file, run the command from my answer that I'll post now

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.x you should run the [new DISM command to repair files](http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx) which is much better compared to sfc:

```
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

It will download the missing or corrupted files from the Internet. But please share the corrupted file before trying to fix it. MS still has no idea why this file gets corrupted so often and maybe your file can help to find the cause.